# Python multiprocessing map and apply doesn't run in parallel?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am confused about the python multiprocessing module. Suppose we write the code like this:

```
pool = Pool()
for i in len(tasks) :
    pool.apply(task_function, (tasks[i],))
```

Firstly i = 0, and the first subprocessor will created and execute the first task. Since we are using the apply instead of apply_async, the main processor is blocked, so there is no chance that i get increment, and execute the second task. So by doing this way, we are actually write a serial code, not run in multiprocessing? So the same is true when we use map instead of map_async? No wonder the result of these tasks comes in order. If this is the truth, we don't even bother to use multiprocessing's map and apply function. Correct me, if I am wrong

Comment: apply function may run in different process but stops the current so it is still a singe thread performance with some overhead. I consider it useless and very confusing :-( especially in comparison to c# where these things work as expected including parallel threads! which don't work in python at all. Try the apply_async method or make processes your self. That approach works fine, but it is not as convenient :-(

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.apply):

> apply(func[, args[, kwds]])
>
> Equivalent of the apply() built-in function. It blocks until 
>   the result is ready, so apply_async() is better suited for 
>   performing work in parallel. Additionally, func is only executed 
>   in one of the workers of the pool.

So yes, if you want to delegate work to another process and return control to your main process, you have to use `apply_async`.

Regarding your statement:

> If this is the truth, we don't even bother to use
>   multiprocessing's map and apply function

Depends on what you want to do. For example `map` will split the arguments into chunks and apply the function for each chunk in the different processes of the pool, so you *are* achieving parallelism. This would work for your example:

```
pool.map(task_funcion, tasks)
```

It will split `tasks` into pieces, and then call `task_function` on each process from the pool with the different pieces of `tasks`. So for example you could have Process1 running `task_function(task1)`, Process2 running `task_function(task2)` all at the same time.

Comment: Why does `multiprocessing.apply` even exists? Is there any use for it?